# trying to connect to local server using php (ftp_connect)

Tags: php, permissions, server

I have a server set up with Apache2 on linux and I'm trying to upload a file to that server.

I am using:

```
$conn = ftp_connect("localhost") or die("Server connection failed.");
```

to achieve this, though it is not working.

I have tried a "wget" command to the same server though that failed also with this response:

```
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:21... failed: Connection refused.
```

Does anybody know how to allow my server to be used in the ftp_connect php command?

Thank you very much guys.

Comment: Apache is not an ftp server

Comment: Backing up a second: what are you trying to do here? PHP code can manipulate files on the server directly; there's generally no reason you need FTP for that.

Comment: trying to upload a file, run an already written algorithm on it via the command line, save the results some where on the server temporarily and provide them as a download for the client.

I know how to implement the second part but it was uploading the file that was causing me bother and I thought that a "get" method was the more favorable option, it seems I was wrong and am trying with the "post" method now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by Maerlyn, Apache is an HTTP server. That means it can only communicate via the HTTP protocol.

You are attempting to connect to an FTP-server, that's a completely different thing(!).

However, what I think you want to do is not connect to an FTP server and upload files via that; rather what you want to do is use an HTTP POST (or PUT) request to upload a file to the server.

The way to do that is to have an HTML form with a `method="post"`, containing an `<input type="file">` element. When this is submitted, the PHP page will receive the file in the `$_FILES` superglobal, which you can then move to wherever you want it using functions such as `move_uploaded_file()`.

For a more in-depth explenation, please see the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: Ah brilliant! thank you very much guys! Sorry I'm a little green, only started looking at all this server stuff last week so my understanding of it all is still very rudimentary.
I was using a "get" method in the html to upload, do something to the file and then move to a new page to display results data, can I display the results data on the same page with a "post" method?

Comment: for some reason the file is not moving, so my exact setup at the moment is as follows:

$formfile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$upldfile = move_uploaded_file($formfile, "./uploads/") or die ("File not moved correctly");

This is in its own php file that is called from the form in another html file written as:

<form action="./down.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

it is echoing the "or die" text

Comment: There are 2 problems in the code you just gave; the 1st argument should be the path to the uploaded file (not just the name provided on the HTML page. This is stored in the tmp_name field of the $_FILES array). Furthermore the 2nd argument to move_uploaded_file isn't just a path to a directory, but should also include a filename. In your code it's missing the filename. Change it to `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "./uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"])` and it should work (unless it failes for a different reason ofc.)